# Django: apply constraint on 'choices'-based property on model

Tags: python, django

I want to apply a constraint in the following way:

Imagine that you have a Charfield property with some choices.

```py
class ExampleChoices(models.TextChoices):
    A = "A", "a"
    B = "B", "b"
    C = "C", "c"
    D = "D", "c"

class ExampleModel(models.Model, PublishModelMixin):
    property = models.CharField(choices=ExampleChoices.choices, default=ExampleChoices.A)
```

I now want to put constraints on two of those choices, rules:

1. If choice C is used I want it to be unique and cannot be used anywhere else, with that D cannot be used at all
2. The same rule applies for when D is used, D must be unique and C cannot be used anywhere else.
3. In the previous occasions all other choices can just be used like normally.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) for this purpose.

Since the `clean()` method is not called automatically in `save()` method, we need to add it (or `full_clean()`) call there.

Here is an example:

```
class ExampleChoices(models.TextChoices):
    A = "A", "a"
    B = "B", "b"
    C = "C", "c"
    D = "D", "c"

class ExampleModel(models.Model, PublishModelMixin):
    property = models.CharField(choices=ExampleChoices.choices, default=ExampleChoices.A)

    def clean(self):
        if self.property == ExampleChoices.C:
            if ExampleModel.objects.filter(property=ExampleChoices.C).exclude(pk=self.pk).exists():
                raise models.ValidationError("Choice C must be unique.")
            if ExampleModel.objects.filter(property=ExampleChoices.D).exists():
                raise models.ValidationError("Choice D cannot be used when choice C is selected.")
        elif self.property == ExampleChoices.D:
            if ExampleModel.objects.filter(property=ExampleChoices.D).exclude(pk=self.pk).exists():
                raise models.ValidationError("Choice D must be unique.")
            if ExampleModel.objects.filter(property=ExampleChoices.C).exists():
                raise models.ValidationError("Choice C cannot be used when choice D is selected.")
        return super().clean()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Looks promising, thanks!

Comment: Passed the test, had to use `self.clean()` in the overridden `save()` method though, because of my other properties (full_clean was a bit too rigorous), but for the rest it works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional indexes

```py
class ExampleChoices(models.TextChoices):
    A = "A", "a"
    B = "B", "b"
    C = "C", "c"
    D = "D", "c"

class ExampleModel(models.Model, PublishModelMixin):
    property = models.CharField(choices=ExampleChoices.choices, default=ExampleChoices.A)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
              fields=['property']
              condition=Q(property=ExampleChoices.C),
              name="only_one_row_with_c"
            )
        ]
```